# measure valley width 2d, matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, image-processing

I have a 2d image, I have locations where local minimas occurs.
I want to measure the width of the valleys "leading" to those minimas.
I need either the radii of the circles or ellipses fitted to these valley.
An example attached here, dark red lines on the peaks contours is what I wish to find.
Thanks.

[image: peaks width example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am partially extending the answer of @Lucas.

Given a threshold `t` I would consider the points `P_m` that are below `t` and closer  to a certain point `m` of minimum of your `f` (given a characteristic scale length `r`).

(You said your data are noisy; to distinguish minima and talk about wells, you need to estimate such `r`. In your example it can be for instance `r=4`, i.e. half the distance between the minima).

Then you have to consider a metric for each *well region* `P_m`, say for example

```
 metric(P_m) = .5 * mean{ maximum vertical diameter of P_m ,  
                     maximum horizontal diameter of P_m}.
```

In your picture `metric(P_m) = 2` for both wells.

---

On the whole, in terms of pseudo-code you may consider

```
 M := set of local minima of f

 for_each(minimum m in M){

      P_m += {p : d(p,m) < r and f(r)<t}  % say that += is the push operation in a Stack

 }

 radius_of_region_around(m) = metric(P_m);  %
```

Comment: ok, that r is exactlly what I don't have, and want to estimate by measuring the area where my minima is starting to evolve. I don't want the either thresh it, or estimate a radius I want to measure it :-),

Comment: that r is just to isolate the minima. Hoping that the wells characteristic radius is lower than r. Otherwise all the wells com-penetrate themselves.

Comment: In your picture the wells radius is about 2; while my r can be about 4. If you have this distinction of scales, then the algorithm I suggested would work. If not, i.e. there is not clear distinction among wells, I would start thinking maybe to some frequency-like analysis.

Comment: Acrobe, you have a point there! I need to think for a while, before my next comment .. :)

Comment: Good. Let us discuss then! @matlabit

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making a list of points that describe the values at the edge of your ellipse, perhaps by finding all the points where it crosses a threshold.

```
above = data > threshold
```

apply a simple edge detector

```
edges = EdgeDetector(above)
```

find coordinates of edges

```
[row,col] = find(edges)
```

Then apply this ellipse fitter http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3215-fitellipse

Comment: Hi, I'm not interested in just edges, I'm interested in "edges" that are the borders of  my local minimas. The image I attached of the meshc is a simple example, in reality, the valleys in my data are not so distinct, and the data is very noisy, so applying edge detector might union many of them. The ellipse fitter is cool though..

Comment: The edge detector bit is only to convert above threshold and below threshold to a list of edges. Replace, the `above = data > threshold` bit with whatever you want to detect inside and outside of the minimum. I only supplied those three lines of code as a rough guide to how you might use the package.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here you have access to the `x`, `y` and `z` data and are not processing a given JPG (or so) image. Then, you can use the function `contourc` to your advantage:

```
% plot some example function
figure(1), clf, hold on    
[x,y,z] = peaks;
surf(x,y,z+10,'edgecolor', 'none')
grid on, view(44,24)

% generate contour matrix. The last entry is a 2-element vector, the last
% element of which is to ensure the right algorithm gets called (so leave 
% it untouched), and the first element is your threshold.
C = contourc(x(1,:), y(:,1), z, [-4 max(z(:))+1]);

% plot the selected points
plot(C(1,2:end), C(2,2:end), 'r.')
```

Then use [this superfast ellipse fitting tool](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22684-ellipse-fit-direct-method) to fit an ellipse through those points and find all the parameters of the ellipse you desire.

I suggest you read `help contourc` and `doc contourc` to find out why the above works, and what else you can use it for.